# Python type hinting unions

Tags: python, python-3.x, type-hinting

I have a function with two arguments:

```py
def same_type_params(param1: Union[str, int], param2: Union[str, int]):
    pass
```

How do I constrain that the types of `param1` and `param2` are equal? i.e. either both `str` or both `int`

Comment: What do you mean by "constrain"? None of this is enforced at runtime.

Comment: @Chris Of course not. It's still a constraint that `mypy`, for example, will honor, though.

Comment: I just want to make sure OP knows that. "Constrain" suggests something else to me.

Comment: Yes I understand. As @juanpa.arrivillaga suggested I meant only to convey the constraint.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use a [type variable](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.TypeVar):

```
from typing import TypeVar
T = TypeVar('T', str, int)
def same_type_params(param1: T, param2: T) -> None:
    pass
```